# How to resolve the problem"System.Double has too many dimensions"

Tags: c#, .net, matlab

I want convert `MWNumericArray` to a C# array. But I can't use the `ToArray()` and `ToVector()` functions. I don't know where is wrong.

I want turn a `MWNumericArray abs_U_lv` to Array `A` and used `ToArray()` and `ToVector(MWNumericArray.component.Real)`. Both of the two functions can't work.

```
    Class1 trans = new Class1();

    MWArray[] input = new MWArray[] { r_h, l_h, r_l, l_l, l_0, r_0, r, u_hv, f1 };

    MWArray[] output = new MWArray[6];


    trans.Transformator(6, ref output, input);

    MWNumericArray Abs_U_lv = output[0] as MWNumericArray;
    //MWNumericArray Ang_U_lv = output[1] as MWNumericArray;
    MWNumericArray Abs_I_hv = output[2] as MWNumericArray;
    //MWNumericArray Ang_I_hv = output[3] as MWNumericArray;
    MWNumericArray Abs_I_lv = output[4] as MWNumericArray;
    //MWNumericArray Ang_I_lv = output[5] as MWNumericArray;

    //var A= (double[])Abs_U_lv.ToArray();
    //var C = (double[,])Abs_I_hv.ToArray();
    //var E = (double[,])Abs_I_lv.ToArray();
    /*double[,] A = new double[Fre.Count,1 ];
    double[,] C = new double[1, Fre.Count];
    double[,] E = new double[1, Fre.Count];*/

    var A = (double[,])Abs_U_lv.ToArray();

    //System.TypeLoadException: ""System.Double[,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,]" der Assembly "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" hat zu viele Dimensionen."

    var C = (double[,])Abs_I_hv.ToArray();
    var E = (double[,])Abs_I_lv.ToArray();
```

> System.TypeLoadException: ""System.Double[,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,]" der Assembly "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" hat zu viele Dimensionen."

Comment: Your code is Matlab or C#?

Comment: Did you try double[][]?